# What is the equivalent of Split function in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dynamic formula in google sheet that splits a rept string into multiple columns using this formula: =split(rept(A1,B1)," ").

But I can't seem to figure out how to do this in excel. Any suggestion would be helpful.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IcIvhuwA3z2lngz-l4TwuenPgCMOGdCwe_Ukhu_f5zQ/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Wow. I've never heard of a spreadsheet function that *outputs to* multiple cells, but [that's what the docs say it does](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `SEQUENCE()` function access then try-

```
=TRANSPOSE(INDEX(A1,SEQUENCE(B1,,,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Yup, you don't need to split anything if the actual splitting isn't the objective per se! Was going to add this =)

Comment: Woah this is even easier! Appreciate this a lot!

Comment: Neat! You don't even need the transpose though do you, =INDEX(A1,SEQUENCE(,B1,,0))

Comment: @Tom Sharpe Good tips!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `FILTERXML()` to mimic a split funcitonality:

[image]

Formula in `A3`:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&REPT(A1&"</s><s>",B1)&"</s></t>","//s[.!='']"))
```

The above will spill the returned array horizontally using Microsoft365. If you don't have acces to dynamic array funtionality, you could use indices to return values from the resulting array.

For further explainations and examples using `FILTERXML()` I'd like to refer you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194) Q&A on the topic.

Comment: Thank you, solves my problem! I really hope excel has a much simple way to do this.

Comment: @ZyreSoriano. If your task is not actually to find the equivalent to "split" functionality but just to repeat a certain value, then there is definately a better way. See the answer by Harun24HR for an example.